# How can I add an action link to jquery table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add an action link to my jquery table so I can navigate to another page. This is what I've tried

```
var $row = $("<tr>", { class: "info" }).prop('id', id);
                                $row.append($("<td>").html(item.name));
                                $row.append($("<td>").html(item.code));
                                $row.append($("<td>").html(item.shortName));
                                $row.append($("<td>").html(item.squadMarketValue));
                                $row.append($("<td>").html(item.crestURL));
                                $row.append($("<td>").html(id));
                                $row.append($('<td><a href="/Leagues/Edit/"' + id + '"></a></td>'));
                                $row.appendTo($('#teamsTable'));
```

A little cell appears but on click it does not do anything.

Comment: Looks like something else is stopping the event to happen.

Comment: What's the value of id? Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: well there is nothing to click since there is nothing in the anchor.

Comment: You need something inside the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Hi Dave - if your question is answered please accept the solution by clicking green check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing inside the `<a>` tag to click on. The click doesn't activate the `<a>` tag at all, because the tag is not even displayed in the view. You need to have something to display the `<a>` tag. So add something to get it displayed in the DOM.

```
$row.append($('<td><a href="/Leagues/Edit/"' + id + '">Edit</a></td>'));
// ----------------------------------------------------^^^^
```

Credits: [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457479/how-can-i-add-an-action-link-to-jquery-table/43457599#comment73970762_43457479).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler for dynamic content.
For example:

```js
var item = {
  name: "Lala Land",
  code: "123",
  shortName: "land",
  squadMarketValue : "Lala",
  crestURL : "google.com"
}

var id='table-row';

var $row = $("<tr>", {
  class: "info"
}).prop('id', id);

$row.append($("<td>").html(item.name));
$row.append($("<td>").html(item.code));
$row.append($("<td>").html(item.shortName));
$row.append($("<td>").html(item.squadMarketValue));
$row.append($("<td>").html(item.crestURL));
$row.append($("<td>").html(id));
$row.append($('<td><a href="/Leagues/Edit/' + id + '">Click me</a></td>'));
$row.appendTo($('#teamsTable'));

$('#'+id).on('click' , 'a', function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='teamsTable'>
  <tr class="info"></tr>
</table>
```